# getting mac address with java applet

Tags: java, applet, mac-address

I read on some sites that getting a client's mac address is possible only if he's using explorer browser, or if he's on my the same LAN as me. On other sites I read it's always possible...

What are the restrictions of getting a client's mac address through a java applet? (except for signed applet, user's confirmation and setting the manifest to `permissions: all-permissions` )

Comment: For what purpose? Are you aware that MAC addresses can be changed by the user? And that there's nothing useful you can do with them in Java exception display them? And that they shouldn't be used as unique system identifiers, because they ain't?

Comment: I am aware to that fact. However, end-users do not end to change their mac address and a user's mac address is not possible to get without his permission so it could provide a good additional security to the password (assuming the user is connecting through one computer only).